# Getting Deployment Group Arn for LifecycleEventHookExecutionId in Lambda Event

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy a Lambda function with pre and post hook without using SAM.

```
import json
import boto3
import os

codedeploy = boto3.client('codedeploy')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Pre-traffic logic goes here
    print("Pre-Traffic Hook: Checks before traffic shift begins")
    print(event)
    deployment_id = event['DeploymentId']
    lifecycle_event_hook_execution_id = event['LifecycleEventHookExecutionId']
    function_to_test = os.environ.get('NewVersion')
    params = {
        'deploymentId': deployment_id,
        'lifecycleEventHookExecutionId': lifecycle_event_hook_execution_id,
        'status': "Succeeded"
    }
    print(params)
    # Pass CodeDeploy the prepared validation test results
    response = codedeploy.put_lifecycle_event_hook_execution_status(
        **params)
```

From Cloudwatch I got this output,

```
{'DeploymentId': 'd-CBEWCVG33', 'LifecycleEventHookExecutionId': 'arn:aws:codedeploy:us-east-1:xxxxxx:deploymentgroup:MyLambdaCodeDeployApp/MyLambdaDeploymentGroup', 'FunctionName': 'MyLambdaFunction', 'TargetVersion': '2', 'TargetAlias': 'live'}
```

For `LifecycleEventHookExecutionId` I am expecting some id, but it is giving DeploymentGroup ARN.
With this I couldn't update the Event Hook Execution Status.

```
InvalidLifecycleEventHookExecutionIdException: An error occurred (InvalidLifecycleEventHookExecutionIdException) 
when calling the PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus operation: The lifecycleEventHookExecutionId is invalid
```

In SAM, i can see the ExecutionID. But while creating it manually, why it is not giving the ID.